# Array is null. Pushing from NSObject to AppDelegate

Tags: objective-c, ios4, xcode4, nsmutablearray

Again, Xcode newb here ... So I'm having trouble getting my Items (code not shown but almost identical to the List query) and List arrays to show any data or even count. In the Dbase implementation file I can print out the array ... but in UWLAppDelegate I get nothing. I've seen examples of this issue on here but they don't seem to fix the issue. FYI, I'm using Preview Xcode also. So some things might not look right.

I've tried initializing as described on here and the tutorial:

```
    NSMutableArray *tempArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
self.listArray = tempArray;
```

... but still no dice.

```
UWLAppDelegate.m  

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {
[self copyDatabase];

self.itemArray = [NSMutableArray array];
self.listArray = [NSMutableArray array];

NSLog(@"Items Array: %@",self.itemArray);
NSLog(@"List Array: %@",self.listArray);

[Dbase getDisplayData:[self getDBPath]];
[Dbase getListDisplayData:[self getDBPath]];
}
```

..

```
dbase.m

+ (void) getListDisplayData:(NSString *)dbPath {
UWLAppDelegate *appDelegate = (UWLAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
if(sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK){
    const char *sql = "select id, name from lists";
    sqlite3_stmt *selectstmt;
    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &selectstmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK){
        while(sqlite3_step(selectstmt) == SQLITE_ROW){
            NSInteger primaryKey = sqlite3_column_int(selectstmt, 0);
            Dbase *listObj = [[Dbase alloc] initWithPrimaryKey:primaryKey];
            listObj.dblistname = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 1)];

            listObj.isDirty = NO;

            [appDelegate.listArray addObject:listObj.dblistname];
        }
        //NSLog(@"%@",appDelegate.listArray);
        //NSLog(@"%d", [appDelegate.listArray count]);
    }
} else {
    sqlite3_close(database);
}
}
```

So the commented NSLog's will post data all 6 entires/row I've made from the App. Ideas?

[Objective-C appDelegate array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6170459/objective-c-appdelegate-array) <-- didn't help either. I've looked at other similar questions with no avail. Ideas?

Comment: Did you try debugging your app?

Comment: Why are you not using application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: ?

Comment: well by default it uses:

    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{ }

but i changed it to see if it made any difference and it doesnt.

Comment: Prefixing your getter names with "get" is very un-Objective-C-ish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Frankly there doesn't seem to be a problem. It just seems to be a problem of printing in the wrong order. You have your `NSLog`s before you collect the data. That seems to be the reason why the arrays are empty in your app delegate method while they are printing in `Dbase`'s methods.

Shouldn't it be?

```
self.itemArray = [NSMutableArray array];
self.listArray = [NSMutableArray array];

[Dbase getDisplayData:[self getDBPath]];
[Dbase getListDisplayData:[self getDBPath]];

NSLog(@"Items Array: %@",self.itemArray);
NSLog(@"List Array: %@",self.listArray);
```

Comment: They would still be empty. :)

Comment: There are never added any items to them.

Comment: @WTP Quoting the OP – "In the Dbase implementation file I can print out the array", I take this to mean that the commented `NSLog`s are printing the proper array. So data is being added in the `+[Dbase getDisplayData]` method.